# How can I generate QR Code in laravel when we scan QR Code it show url of another page and in that page show user data in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

How I send data to QR Code with URL when we scan it show data of user where user is not auth.

I have make QR Code and make blade file but I don't know how to send user data in that page.

Comment: you can use this simple api to make qr code : `https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes`

Comment: @Vishnu But I don't want to use this api. I have already make. my question is how can I send data in QR Code?

Comment: check this tutorial : https://makitweb.com/generate-qr-code-using-simple-qrcode-in-laravel-8/

Comment: @AbdullahAfridi I have used milon/barcode can you tell me how can I attach data with that QR Code?

Comment: what data you want to send and show it on QrCode

Comment: @AbdullahAfridi There is one link of view that show one page and I have show user data on that page and data is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller:

```
 public function userData(Request $request) 
{
    $qr_data['user'] = User::where('id', $request->id)->get();
    $qr_data['link'] = "www.google.com";

    return view('path_to_your_view',$qr_data);
}
```

In your view:

```
{!! DNS1D::getBarcodeHTML("$user->name", 'User') !!}
{!! DNS1D::getBarcodeHTML("$link", 'Link') !!}
```

Try this hope it work.

Comment: full tutorial link: https://codeanddeploy.com/blog/laravel/how-to-generate-barcode-in-laravel-8

Comment: I have drop message for appreciate your suggestion but I don't know why it's not here. It's work properly for me. Thanks for your time and help. 

Comment: No problem happy for you that it worked for you.